Warum "Wir treffen uns in dem Bistro" und nicht "Wir treffen uns in der Bistro?" Warum Dativ?
Warum ist

Wir treffen uns in dem Bistro.

richtig?
Ich dachte, dass man

Wir treffen uns in der Bistro?

sagen kann. Warum muss ich Dativ benutzen?

Welchen Fall halten Sie für den korrekten und warum?

in der Bistro wäre auch Dativ, wenn Bistro weiblich wäre. Die Frage ist also nicht "Dativ oder nicht?", sondern "weiblich oder männlich?"

@JonathanScholbach ... oder sächlich

@Arsak Oh ja, stimmt :)

Weil die Präposition in mit dem Dativ steht, wenn ein Ort gemeint ist.

Wir sitzen in dem Bistro.

Wenn eine Richtung gemeint ist, steht in mit dem Akkusativ. Der wäre aber das Bistro, denn es ist im Nominativ das Bistro, also Neutrum.

Wir gehen in das Bistro.


Wäre Bistro weiblich, wie die Metro, dann hieße es in der Tat wir treffen uns in der Bistro.
Das Bistro ist jedoch sächlich, daher treffen wir uns im (in dem) Bistro.
Bei männlichen Substantiven (der Prater') ist es übrigens auch in dem Prater, wo man sich trifft.
') Prater: Vergnügungspark in Wien.

Nur eine Anmerkung: In Österreich ist es das Tunnel... also nicht das beste Beispiel ;)

Ist's so besser? ;)
